# Troubleshooting Node.js Express Server Routing Issue

Tags: node.js, express, url-routing

I tried this simple code in NodeJS:

```
const express=require("express");

const app=express();

const accounts=[]

app.use("/dashboard",function(req,res,next){
    res.send(accounts);
    next();
})

app.post("/dashboard/add-account/:address{6}",function(req,res,next){
    accounts.push(req.params.address);
    console.info(accounts);
    next();
})

app.put("/modify-account/:index/:address{6}",function(req,res){
    accounts[req.params.index]=req.params.address;
    res.send(accounts);
})

app.delete("/dashboard/delete-account/:index[0-9]",function(req,res){
    accounts[req.params.index]="";
    console.info(accounts);
})

app.listen(3001,"127.0.0.1",650,()=>{console.info("Server is ready ...")});
```

By sending this request: `http://localhost:3001/dashboard/add-account/0x1234`

But nothing logged on the console!
this code is a simple code to learn ExpressJS and I am new to routing and middleware functions. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify what type of request you're attempting to make to `http://localhost:3001/dashboard/add-account/0x1234`. If it's a GET request (i.e. from a browser), you wouldn't see anything logged because you don't have a GET route handler.

Try adding something like the following to get started:

```
app.get("/dashboard/add-account/:address{6}",function(req,res,next){
    console.info("TODO: render add account form or similar here.");
    next();
})
```